# Total resistance of circuit

Tags: resistors, thevenin

Hi I'm struggling a bit with obtaining the total resistance of this [circuit](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/6ma5ta/diamond-challenge/), I know it's an easy one I'm just a bit confused on how  the resistors are merged using parallel and series operations, here's an image:

[image: Offending Circuit]

The overall goal is to obtain Thevenin's equivalent circuit so when obtaining \$R_{th}\$ the circuit is open between nodes A and B, and the voltage source is shorted out.

I've tried

- First

  - Rp = R1//R3
  - Rs = Rp + R2
  - Rt = Rs//R4 = **2.29**
- Second

  - Rs1 = R1 + R2 = 9
  - Rs2 = R3 + R4 = 8
  - Rt = Rs1//Rs2 = **4.23**

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for Rth, you do exactly as you said (remove RL such that there is an open-circuit between A and B, then shut V2 off and measure equivalent resistance from A to B).

First, remove the resistor and short V2. If you label nodes at this point, it will help you to redraw the circuit in a more typical fashion:

[image: circuit]

Convince yourself that that is true, and from there you should be golden :)

Comment: thx for replying, According, to your diagram, \$ R_{th} \$ should be 1 ohms?

Comment: +1 for the arrow using the ground symbol :) @Triztian it is

Comment: I was hoping someone else would appreciate that xP